# Cast parent class to child class

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have Message class which I have extended and added new property.

```
class ChildMessage: Message 
{
prop...
}
```

While trying to add Message Class to ChildMessage list I get Null reference for added class.

```
var myChildList =new List<ChildMessage> ();
var myParentClass = new Message();
myChildList.add(myParentClass as ChildMessage)

myChildList[0] == null //Always return null
```

What is wrong with my code? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is because a true instance of `Message` is not a `ChildMessage`, whereas an instance of `ChildMessage` is a `Message`.

Unless `myParentClass` is *actually* instantiated with `ChildMessage` you cannot use the cast operator to force a forward cast as the actual underlying type is `Message`.

That said, there are `implicit` and `explicit` cast operators available for use on types, so you could perhaps create one that takes a `Message` and outputs a `ChildMessage`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

---

Knowing that you are given these types and you have no choice but to use them, you have two options in order to extend that type.

**First Option**

Use the decorator/wrapper pattern to wrap a `Message` inside a `ChildMessage`:

```
class ChildMessage
{
    private Message _innerMessage;

    public ChildMessage(Message innerMessage)
    {
        _innerMessage = innerMessage;
    }
}
```

You then expose either the `Message` or its properties through the `ChildMessage` class.

**Second Option**

This is just as feasible, inherit from the `Message`, but when you want to make a `ChildMessage` from a `Message` you will need to *convert it*, not cast it:

```
class ChildMessage : Message
{
    public ChildMessage(Message m)
    {
        // Instantiate properties by copying from m
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, how I can solve this problem? I need to extend Parent Class and add several new properties and then add new Parent Classes to extended class.

Comment: @reinierpost I'm not saying "inheritance works by making parent classes", I'm saying a common example of inheritance is taking a lot of derived types and using the common base type of them to achieve some common behaviour.

Comment: Ah, I see - yes that may work while you're still designing classes and the hierarchy isn't carved in stone yet due to other code depending on it.  I'm not too fond of inheritance myself.

Answer (score 3):

I think you somehow got it the wrong way - normaly you might want something like:

```
var myList =new List<Message> ();
var myChildObject = new ChildMessage();
myList.add(myChildObject)

myList[0] as ChildMessage == null // should not return null
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change your code in this way

```
var myChildList =new List<Message> (); 
var myChildClass = new ChildMessage(); 
myChildList.add(myChildClass as Message)
```

Now you have a List where the objects are of type ChildMessage or
other types derived from Message. 
You could check the correct type later when you use the objects stored in the list.

Comment: I need to add Message class to the List. I get Message class from one object and need to store it to extended Message class.

Comment: I am confused now. If class B derives from class A and C also from A you could store every instances of A,B,C in a List<A>. Of course you need a mechanism to know the exact type of object when you retrieve elements from List<A>. This could be done in numerous ways in C# (look for keywords 'as', 'is' and 'typeof')

Comment: I have Class A and I get this from another object as new instance. I need to store to List<B>. Where B:A. How to cast A to B?

Comment: An instance of A is not an instance of B, an instance of B is also an instance of A. See the more detailed @Adam Houldsworth answer-

Answer (score 2):

A cast on an object cannot be used to *change* its type: it is not a *conversion*.
It only serves to *tell* the type of an object: you explain that you want to use the object as an object of that type; and the object must already be of that type, or you'll get an error (at least in a decent language such as C#).

Casting objects is meaningful because, thanks to inheritance, objects may be of multiple types at once.

In your code, every `ChildMessage` is a `Message`, but the  `Message`s you create are not `ChildMessage`s, so trying to use them as such fails.

By contrast, "casts" from, say, integers to reals, or vice versa, may actually be conversions. (Terminology in IT is a hopeless jungle.)